# Scrapy - Every Page is scraped but scrapy wraps around and scrapes first x amount of pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
class HomedepotcrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'homeDepotCrawl'
    #allowed_domains = ['homedepot.com']
    start_urls =['https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=0']

    def parse(self, response):

        for item in self.parseHomeDepot(response):
            yield item

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)



    def parseHomeDepot(self, response):

        items = response.css('.plp-pod')
        for product in items:
            item = HomedepotSpiderItem()

    #get SKU
            productSKU = product.css('.pod-plp__model::text').getall()

    #get rid of all the stuff i dont need
            productSKU = [x.strip(' ') for x in productSKU] #whiteSpace
            productSKU = [x.strip('\n') for x in productSKU]
            productSKU = [x.strip('\t') for x in productSKU]
            productSKU = [x.strip(' Model# ') for x in productSKU] #gets rid of the model name
            productSKU = [x.strip('\xa0') for x in productSKU] #gets rid of the model name



            item['productSKU'] = productSKU

            yield item
```

**Explanation of the Problem**

Here is part of the program that I have been working on to scrape data. I left out my code for scraping other fields because I did not think it was necessary to include with this post. When I run this program and export data to excel, I get the first 240 items (10 pages). That goes up to row 241 of my spreadsheet(The first row is occupied by labels). Then starting from row 242, the first 241 rows are repeated once again. Then again on row 482 and 722.

**The Scraper outputs the first 240 items 3 times**

**EDIT**
So I was looking through the log of during scraping and it turned out that every page was getting scraped. The last page is:

https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=696&Ns=None>

then afterwards the logfile is showing the first page getting scraped again, which is:

https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default

I assume because of..
[image]

The terminal command that I'm using to export to excel is:

```
scrapy crawl homeDepotCrawl -t csv -o - > "(File Location)"
```

**Edit**: The reason why I am using this command is because when exporting, Scrapy appends the scraped data to the file, so this erases the target file and just creates it again.

The code that I used to derive getting all pages is:

```
<a class="hd-pagination__link" title="Next" href="/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&amp;Nao=24&amp;Ns=None" data-pagenumber="2"></a>
```

Originally I thought it was the website that was causing this unexpected behavior so on settings.py I changed `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = 0` and I added a delay but that did not change anything.

**So what I would like help with:**

-Figuring out why the CSV output only takes the first 240 Items (10 Pages) and repeats 3 times

-How ensure the spider doesn't go back to the first page after scraping the first 30

Comment: Did you check the log? Did you try inspecting the HTML of the responses that have unexpected content?

Comment: I did check the pagination portion of the 10th page and it was pretty much identical (as far as I could tell) to the other pages

Comment: Something I might be missing - why would the spider ever stop scraping? It seems that the code should run until an error occurs, as for every response the spider expects a next button to appear. Is it possible there is a hidden error?

Comment: @kmaork I didn’t change anything in the other files so I wouldn't think so unless home depot's website is blocking me from scraping many pages

Comment: I still don't understand, at what point is the spider supposed to stop?

Comment: @kmaork Sorry, the spider should stop at the very last page, there are 1,129 items that come from the search result, 24 items per page, so 1129 % 24 = 47 pages. The code I posted scrapes the first 10 pages (240 Items) then does first 10 pages, 3 more times.

Comment: @chrisHG I think your code may be fine. Check the second part of my answer below where I manually test the site itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this. The main difference is I'm grabbing the info from the json stored on the page and I'm paginating myself by recognizing the `Nao` is the product offset. The code is much shorter too:

```
import requests,json,re
product_skus = set()
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=%s'
for page_num in range(1,1000):
    url = base_url % (page_num*24)
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(re.search(r'digitalData\.content=(.+);', res.text).group(1))
    prev_len = len(product_skus)
    for product in json_data['product']:
        product_skus.add(product['productInfo']['sku'])
    if len(product_skus) == prev_len: break # this line is optional and can determine when you want to break
```

Additionally, it looks like the Home Depot pages **repeat** every 10 pages (at least in what you sent) which is why you're seeing the 240 limitation. Here is an example from browsing it myself:

- [HD Page 5](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=96&Ns=None&storeSelection=1002,6627,654,1039,1048)
- [HD Page 15](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=336&Ns=None)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed wrapping around to the beginning, chrome dev tools reveals that 'next' points to the first set of items when you reach the end.

You can detect and circumvent this with logic that looks at the current item index:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath/N-5yc1vZbv1wZhsy?experienceName=default&Nao=696&Ns=None'
>>> parsed = urlparse(url)
>>> page_index = int(parse_qs(parsed.query)['Nao'][0])
>>> page_index
696
```

and edit your `if next_page_url` logic to include logic like `and page_index > last_page_index`

Comment: so under if next_page_url , I would increment last_page_index by 1, then check if it is less that page index?

Comment: more like `last = 0`, and then put the above in a function like `get_page_index(url)`, and your logic would be `new = get_page_index(next_page); if new <= last: break; last = new`